# How to solve importing python packages " No module named "?

Tags: python, macos

I am coming across a strange problem, I already installed python packages but it doesn't recognize them. please note that some packages are recognizable.

An example of importing a package

```
ActivePython 2.7.5.6 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 16 2013, 23:07:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Whenever I try to install it using Pip like

```
sudo pip install requests
```

I got this message whenever I try to install the same package.

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

What should I do to solve this problem ?

**UPDATE_1**

```
pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Clearly `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is not in your `sys.path`. I can't tell you why, as I'm not familiar with OSX, but that is your problem

Comment: Does `python3` have the packages installed?

Comment: Please run `pip --version` and tell us what that outputs. Alternatively, try installing requests using `sudo python -m pip install requests`.

Comment: @poke please, check the update, I have run the command

Answer (score 2):

Find where pip installs your package and add the path to

```
 export PYTHONPATH=<path>
 #my path was /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

in your .bashrc or .profile file.